# My car brakes gets stuck sometimes

Tags: honda, brakes, jazz

I have a Honda Jazz, and sometimes when I step on the brakes it sometimes gets stuck. It's like there's compressed air preventing the brake pedal to go all the way to the bottom. As I release and step on it again, a couple of times it releases the air and goes back to normal. Everytime it gets stuck it doesn't stop the car immediately, it's scary as hell and I noticed the brakes got much more smoother.

Whenever it's stuck, it has this same kind of feeling. When pumping the brakes while the engine is off, the pedal range just gets shorter and harder to press down. When turning the engine it just goes back to normal. It's something like that but with the car running the entire time.

What could be the main cause of this?

Comment: Something is wrong with your brake booster.

Comment: brake pedals do not normally go to the floor when the braking system is operating correctly. Even if the booster is faulty the pedal will not go to the floor - just you get no assistance during braking.

Comment: "this same kind of feeling when pumping the brakes while the engine is off the pedals range just gets shorter and harder to press down and when turning the engine it just goes back to normal." That is normal with the engine off. It suggests there is an intermittent fault with the brake servo system, as juhist said. It may be a problem with the "brake assist" system (note, that is not the same as the ABS system) if you car has that option.

Comment: My car has the abs system. Soo do i need to get it replaced? Or are there any possible fixes available for it?